# Update TextField from MUI in conjunction with react-hook-form. onChange is not being called

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form, yup

```
const [userData, setUserData] = useState({
  fullName: "",
  email: "",
}); // Local component state

const onChange = (event) => {
   console.log(event.target.value);
}; // Evente handler

<Grid container spacing={1}>
  <Grid item xs={12} sm={12}>
     <TextField
        required
        id="name"
        name="fullName"
        onChange={onChange}
        label="Name"
        InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
        fullWidth
        value={userData.fullName}
        margin="dense"
       />
         <Typography variant="inherit" color="textSecondary">
           {errors.fullName?.message}
         </Typography>
 </Grid>
   <Grid item xs={12} sm={12}>
     <TextField
        required
        id="email"
        name="email"
        label="Email"
        onChange={onChange}
        fullWidth
        margin="dense"
        value={userData.email}
        {...register("email")}
        error={errors.email ? true : false}
       />
       <Typography variant="inherit" color="textSecondary">
         {errors.email?.message}
        </Typography>
   </Grid>
```

For some reason, onChange is not being called. I also using Yup for validation. I need to update the input value and send it to the API. But for some reason event handler is not being called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overriding the `onChange` prop with the spread of `{...register("email")}` as the `register` call will return an object, where one property is named [`onChange`](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/blob/9ee9750eadf5e7f28f022325795f3f1b3a4296ac/src/logic/createFormControl.ts#L915), which RHF needs to update it's internal form state. Because of that you simply don't need your own `onChange` handler when you use RHF, as you could just access the current `<TextField />` value via RHF directly. You just have to pass your default values either via `useForm` `defaultValues` or pass it to `<Controller />` directly instead of setting it via the `value` prop directly.

I would also recommend to use [`<Controller />`](https://react-hook-form.com/api/usecontroller/controller) as with `register` you are losing the functionality of setting up the correct `ref` for your `<TextField />` input element as it is linked via the `inputRef` prop instead of using `ref` which RHF `register` uses. This comes in handy when you want to instantly focus a field when validiation fails upon submitting the form.

You can also use `<TextField />`'s `error` and `helperText` props to display your error and access it via the `<Controller />` `fieldState` object to get the current validation error (if there is one).

```js
<Grid container spacing={1}>
  <Grid item xs={12} sm={12}>
    <Controller 
      control={control}
      name="fullName"
      defaultValue={userData.fullName}
      render={({ field: { ref, ...field }, fieldState: { error } }) => (
        <TextField
          required
          id={field.name}
          label="Name"
          InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
          fullWidth
          margin="dense"
          error={!!error}
          helperText={error?.message}
        />
      )}
    />
  </Grid>
  <Grid item xs={12} sm={12}>
   <Controller 
      control={control}
      name="email"
      defaultValue={userData.email}
      render={({ field: { ref, ...field }, fieldState: { error } }) => (
        <TextField
          required
          id={field.name}
          label="Name"
          InputLabelProps={{ shrink: true }}
          fullWidth
          margin="dense"
          error={!!error}
          helperText={error?.message}
        />
      )}
    />
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```